# How to find out if a specific cell range has been updated in Google Sheets?

Tags: date, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell

I am making a spreadsheet that requires finding out if a certain cell range has been edited and then add the date that it was edited on. I have the range of cells needed to be edited, and I also don't want the date to change if I sort the table from a different column.

I would think the general idea would look something like this, not actual code just an idea:

```
cell_range=(b2:d2)
if (cell_range)==editted:
     date()

if (table_sort==True):
     date_change==False
```

If anyone knows how to do this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a script for this. try for example:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { 
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { 
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 8);
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  nextCell.setValue(newDate);
}
if( r.getColumn() == 3 ) { 
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 7);
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  nextCell.setValue(newDate);
}
if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { 
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 6);
  var newDate1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
  "GMT+8", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  nextCell.setValue(newDate1);
}}}
```

- `"Sheet1"` = sheet name
- `r.getColumn() == 3` = column C / 3rd column
- `r.offset(0, 7)` = offset timestamp 7 columns to the right on the same row eg column H
- `"GMT+8"` = timezone
- `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"` = date and time format

alternative (untested):

```
function onEdit(e) { 
 if ([2].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) { 
 e.range.offset(0, 7).setValue(new Date()); } 
 if ([3].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) { 
 e.range.offset(0, 6).setValue(new Date()); }
 if ([4].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) { 
 e.range.offset(0, 5).setValue(new Date()); } }
```

Comment: Okay, so just eyeballing this, it should work. However, how would I write and/or implement this code into a specific cell?

Comment: @MichaelPate see perhaps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbGu4.png